# Why was this question deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

[This question was deleted yesterday](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/26638/repairing-cracked-ceramic-mug) by a moderator after I've flagged its answer as NAA.

The question is a simple "How to fix a mug", nothing complex and can't see how it can have more focus.

Even if somehow it's not in a good format, I believe it's essential to give the OP time to edit before deleting it right away.

Can anyone explain what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't a question, it was two questions.  Therefore it falls foul of the *Needs more focus* close reason.

The question was closed and the OP allowed some time to edit it before it was deleted.  Arguably the OP could have been given more time.  However, the OP can still see the question and edit it appropriately.  If that is done, the question can be undeleted and reopened.

Comment: I see those as one, with a possible solution. The question is "how to fix a mug" and the OP brings a possible solution using milk. So can ask them in a comment to move the possible solution to be a self answer. Edit: on second and third reading, you're correct, OP does not suggest using milk to fix the mug but rather "china", which I don't fully get what it means, but guess it's less relevant.